# Exception in Tkinter Callback error, openai api error

Tags: python, tkinter, chatgpt-api

Just before I start this, I'm telling you guys that I'm not a native speaker. So you might think my words suck....nevermind
The program I'm working on is a chatGPT thing. My problem occurred when I changed the method to use openai API, to make it remember the preveious chat. Here's my code

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import openai
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


ctk.set_appearance_mode("light")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")
window = ctk.CTk()
window.title("pyGPT")
window.geometry("500x700")
window.resizable(False, False)
font1 = ctk.CTkFont(size=20)
label1 = ctk.CTkLabel(master=window,
                      text="pyGPT",
                      font=font1)
label1.place(x=25, y=25)
textbox = ctk.CTkTextbox(window,
                         width=300,
                         height=50,
                         corner_radius=10)
textbox.place(x=25,
              y=625)


focusBorderImageData = '''
#a quite long base24 code
'''







borderImageData = '''
#this one too
'''

style = ttk.Style()
borderImage = tk.PhotoImage("borderImage", data=focusBorderImageData)
focusBorderImage = tk.PhotoImage("focusBorderImage", data=focusBorderImageData)

style.element_create("RoundedFrame",
                     "image", borderImage,
                     ("focus", focusBorderImage),
                     border=30, sticky="nsew")
style.layout("RoundedFrame",
             [("RoundedFrame", {"sticky": "nsew"})])

frame1 = ttk.Frame(style="RoundedFrame", padding=20)
text1 = tk.Text(frame1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, wrap="word",
                width=37, height=30)
text1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text1.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: frame1.state(["focus"]))
text1.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: frame1.state(["!focus"]))


window.configure(background="white")
frame1.place(x=25, y=75)
text1.config(state=DISABLED)

frame1.focus_set()








messages = []
conversation_id = 'unique-conversation-id'



def sayit():
    global messages
    OPENAI_API_KEY = "#my openai api key"
    openai.api_key = OPENAI_API_KEY
    messages.append({'role': 'system', 'content': '''From now, just answer to user's question as an AI'''})



    messages.append({'role': 'user', 'content': textbox.get("1.0", "end").strip()})
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine='text-davinci-003',
        prompt=generate_prompt(messages),
        temperature=0.6,
        n=1,
        stop=None
    )
    messages.append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': response.choices[0].text.strip()})
    answer = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
    print(answer)
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(style="RoundedFrame", padding=20)
    text1 = tk.Text(frame1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, wrap="word",
                    width=37, height=30)
    text1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    text1.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: frame1.state(["focus"]))
    text1.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: frame1.state(["!focus"]))


    frame1.place(x=25, y=75)

    frame1.focus_set()
    text1.insert(tk.END, answer)
    text1.config(state=DISABLED)
    text1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    
def generate_prompt(messages):
    role_template = '{role}: {content}'
    return '\n'.join(role_template.format(**message) for message in messages)
    
button = ctk.CTkButton(master=window,
                       width=120,
                       height=50,
                       border_width=0,
                       corner_radius=10,
                       text="➜",
                       command=sayit)
button.place(x=350, y=625)

class SlidePanel(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,
              parent,
              start_pos,
              end_pos):
        super().__init__(master = parent)

        self.start_pos = start_pos + 0.04
        self.end_pos = end_pos - 0.03
        self.width = abs(start_pos - end_pos)

        self.pos = self.start_pos
        self.in_start_pos = True

        self.place(relx = self.start_pos,
             rely = 0.05,
             relwidth = self.width,
             relheight = 0.9)

    def animate(self):
        if self.in_start_pos:
            self.animate_forward()
        else:
            self.animate_backwards()

    def animate_forward(self):
        if self.pos > self.end_pos:
            self.pos -= 0.008
            self.place(relx = self.pos,
              rely = 0.05,
              relwidth = self.width,
              relheight = 0.9)
            self.after(10, self.animate_forward)
        else:
            self.in_start_pos = False

    def animate_backwards(self):
        if self.pos < self.start_pos:
            self.pos += 0.008
            self.place(relx = self.pos, rely = 0.05,
              relwidth = self.width,
              relheight = 0.9)
            self.after(10, self.animate_backwards)
        else:
            self.in_start_pos = True

def move_btn():
    global button_x
    button_x += 0.001
    button.place(relx = button_x,
              rely = 0.5,
              anchor = "center")
    
    if button_x < 0.9:
        window.after(10, move_btn)

def infinite_print():
    global button_x
    button_x += 0.5
    if button_x < 10:
        print("infinite")
        print(button_x)
        window.after(100, infinite_print)

animated_panel = SlidePanel(window, 1.0, 0.7)
style_var = ctk.StringVar(value="on")

button_x = 0.5
button = ctk.CTkButton(window, text = "Menu",
                       command = animated_panel.animate,
                       width=150)
button.place(x=332,y=20)






lang_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
def lang_event():
    global label1, button, style
    if lang_var.get() == 1:
        label1.pack_forget()
        label1 = ctk.CTkLabel(master=window,
                              text="pyGPT",
                              font=font1)
        label1.place(x=25, y=25)
        button = ctk.CTkButton(window, text = 'Menu',
                       command = animated_panel.animate,
                       width=150)
        button.place(x=332,y=20)
    elif lang_var.get() == 2:
        label1.pack_forget()
        label1 = ctk.CTkLabel(master=window,
                              text="챗GPT",
                              font=font1)
        label1.place(x=25, y=25)
        
        button = ctk.CTkButton(window, text = "메뉴",
                       command = animated_panel.animate,
                       width=150)
        button.place(x=332,y=20)
    
lang_1 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=animated_panel,
                            text="English",
                            command=lang_event,
                            variable=lang_var,
                            value=1)
lang_2 = ctk.CTkRadioButton(master=animated_panel,
                            text="한국어",
                            command=lang_event,
                            variable=lang_var,
                            value=2)
lang_1.pack(expand = True,
            fill = "both",
            padx = 20,
            pady = 0)
lang_2.pack(expand = True,
            fill = "both",
            padx = 20,
            pady = 0)

creat_var = ctk.IntVar(value=0)


creat_1 = ctk.CTkSwitch(master=animated_panel,
                      text="Creativiy",
                      variable=creat_var,
                      onvalue=1,
                      offvalue=0)

creat_1.pack(expand = True,
            fill = "both",
            padx = 20,
            pady = 0)




window.mainloop()
```

that's all. and the error was

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_button.py", line 553, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "/Applications/pyGPT 2.0.py", line 585, in sayit
    answer = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'message'
```

i tried to fix this like for few weeks but it was impossible to solve for me..(btw the new mission impossible was amazing) i tried to fix the function, reboot, ask to chatGPT, tried to fix the GPT method.....it didn't work :) could you fix my code, please

Comment: This is telling you that `response['choices'][0]` doesn't have the key `'message'`. Have you examined `response['choices'][0]` to see what it is? You seem to be assuming it's something that it's not.